# Problema com xhtml, ao usar a propriedade appendTo="@(body)" e salvar, não atualiza os dados do meu objeto na bean

Tags: jsf, xhtml, java-bean

```
                              header="Atualizar Contatos" dynamic="true" modal="true" closable="false" appendTo="@(body)">
                        <p:panel id="pnlAtualizarTelefones" class="panel-simples">
                            <c:linha>
                                <c:coluna valueLabel="#{msgCES['Usuario.Tel_Residencia']}: " percentWidth="90" maxWidth="300">
                                    <c:linha>
                                        <c:coluna percentWidth="20">
                                            <p:inputMask value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioContato.nrDdd}" maxlength="2" styleClass="Wid100 coluna-numerica"
                                                    title="#{msgCES['Usuario.DDD_Residencial']}" tabindex="4005" mask="9?9" slotChar="" placeholder="#{msg['Pessoa.DDD']}"/>
                                        </c:coluna>
                                        <c:coluna percentWidth="60">
                                            <p:inputMask value="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioContato.nrTelefone}" maxlength="10" styleClass="Wid100"
                                                    title="#{msgCES['Usuario.Telefone_Residencial']}" tabindex="4006" mask="9?99999999" slotChar="" placeholder="#{msg['Pessoa.Telefone']}"/>
                                        </c:coluna>
                                    </c:linha>
                                </c:coluna>
                            </c:linha>
</p:panel>
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <div align="right">
                                <p:commandButton value="#{msg['gen.confirmar']}" icon="fa fa-check white" global="false"
                                    action="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.atualizarTelefones}" 
                                    process="@this :#{component.namingContainer.clientId}:pnlAtualizarTelefones" 
                                    update="@(.styleUpdateInfoUsuario) :messages"/>
                                <p:commandButton value="#{msg['gen.cancelar']}" icon="fa fa-close white" global="false"
                                    action="#{pesquisaUsuarioBean.fecharDialogAtualizarTelefones}" 
                                    process="@this" />
                            </div>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:dialog>
```

Ao colocar a propriedade appendTo="@(body)", o meu objeto "pesquisaUsuarioBean.usuarioContato" não é atualizado na Bean... eu clico em confirmar, chama a action pesquisaUsuarioBean.atualizarTelefones, mas o objeto não vem com os valores alterados em tela. O problema é que preciso usar algo parecido com o appendTo="@(body)", pois da problemas com o acesso por celular/tablet.

Comment: Duplicada: [Ao usar AppendTo, o object da Bean não atualiza \[fechada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/495781/3774)

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa. Ao invés disso, leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour] para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site e assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.